# Picker text goes out of picker box

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

I am working in Xamarin.Forms where I have a picker like this:

```
 <Picker Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="pickerForSearchMode"  
   Title="Search Mode" BackgroundColor="White" >
    <Picker.Items>
       <x:String>Mode 1</x:String>
       <x:String>Mode 2</x:String>
       <x:String>Mode 3</x:String>
       <x:String>Mode 4</x:String>
    </Picker.Items>
```

It displays perfect on iOS and Android, but in a UWP app it has an issue. The text is displaying outside of the picker like this:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What exactly is wrong?

Comment: I think this is how the UWP platform shows it natively.

Comment: Search Mode is place holder of  picker so it should be display inside picker ..but it is outside picker as lable..so how can i manage it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to use a Custom Renderer, [see the official Xamarin documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/introduction/).

Once the element is rendered, you will need to use the value of the `Title` property and set it as the [`PlaceholderText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.combobox.placeholdertext) of the underlying UWP `ComboBox`.

Check the [official renderer here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/5f8f47ff7ce934f4937ec428b3c1def6286f14da/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WinRT/PickerRenderer.cs) which is in Xamarin Forms, you can see that the `UpdateTitle` method sets the `Header` property of the `ComboBox`. All you will need to do is to replace it with the `PlaceholderText` property in your own renderer.

### Required steps

First you create a custom `Picker` in your PCL project:

```cs
public class PlaceholderPicker : Picker
{
}
```

Replace your `Picker` reference in XAML with the `PlaceholderPicker`:

```xml
<local:PlaceholderPicker VerticalOptions="Center" x:Name="PickerForSearchMode"
  Title="Search Mode" BackgroundColor="White" >
  <Picker.Items>
    <x:String>Mode 1</x:String>
    <x:String>Mode 2</x:String>
    <x:String>Mode 3</x:String>
    <x:String>Mode 4</x:String>
  </Picker.Items>
</local:PlaceholderPicker>
```

You will have to add a namespace import to the page element - `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NamespaceWithTheCustomControl"`.

Now in the UWP project you now create a custom renderer for the control and add a `ExportRenderer` attribute for the assembly to indicate Xamarin Forms to use this renderer in UWP.

```cs
[assembly: ExportRenderer( 
    typeof( PlaceholderPicker ),
    typeof( PlaceholderPickerRenderer ) )]
namespace FormsApp.UWP
{
    public class PlaceholderPickerRenderer : PickerRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
        {            
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.PlaceholderText = Element.Title;
                Control.Header = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that we first set the `PlaceholderText` and then clear the `Header`, which was already set by the default renderer.

I have created a sample solution with this [here on my GitHub](https://github.com/MartinZikmund/Stack-Overflow-2016/tree/master/XamarinFormsUWPPickerWithPlaceholder), you can clone it and try it out yourself :-) .

Comment: Thanks   a lot MZetko.